# React AuthContext doesn't store data in LocalStorage

Tags: reactjs, authentication, frontend, react-context

I'm trying to create an authentification in a mern project with Context and I followed a tutorial on Freecodecamp.
The problem is I can't inject data in LocalStorage.
The data is sent to the backend, but nothing is stored in LS.

My App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate, Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

// Pages
import {
  Home,
  Dashboard,
  MembersPage,
  ProfilePage,
  CreatePost,
  OnePost,
} from "./Pages/index";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  userId: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
};
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(action.payload.token));
      localStorage.setItem("userId", JSON.stringify(action.payload.userId));
      localStorage.setItem(
        "firstName",
        JSON.stringify(action.payload.firstName)
      );
      localStorage.setItem("lastName", JSON.stringify(action.payload.lastName));
      localStorage.setItem("email", JSON.stringify(action.payload.email));
      localStorage.setItem(
        "isAuthenticated",
        JSON.stringify(action.payload.isAuthenticated)
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        token: action.payload.token,
        userId: action.payload.user,
        isAuthenticated: true,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      localStorage.clear();
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        userId: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        dispatch,
      }}
    >
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" exact element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="/profile" exact element={<ProfilePage />} />
        <Route path="/members" exact element={<MembersPage />} />
        <Route path="/posts" exact element={<CreatePost />} />
        <Route path="/posts/:id" exact element={<OnePost />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
      </Routes>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The Login.jsx:

```
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const initialState = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    isSubmitting: false,
    errorMessage: null,
  };
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(initialState);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setData({
      ...data,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  };
  const handleLogin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setData({
      ...data,
      isSubmitting: true,
      errorMessage: null,
    });
    axios({
      method: "post",
      headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
      url: "http://localhost:8080/home/login",
      data: {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
      },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        navigate("/dashboard");
        if (res.ok) {
          return res.json();
        }
        throw res;
      })
      .then((resJson) => {
        dispatch({
          type: "LOGIN",
          payload: resJson,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setData({
          ...data,
          isSubmitting: false,
          errorMessage: error.message || error.statusText,
        });
      });
  };

  return (
          <Box
            component="form"
            onSubmit={handleLogin}
            noValidate
          >
            <label htmlFor="email">
              Email Address
              <input
                type="text"
                value={data.email}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                name="email"
                id="email"
              />
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="password">
              Password
              <input
                type="password"
                value={data.password}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                name="password"
                id="password"
              />
            </label>
            {data.errorMessage && (
              <span className="form-error">{data.errorMessage}</span>
            )}

            <button disabled={data.isSubmitting}>
              {data.isSubmitting ? "Loading..." : "Login"}
            </button>
            <Grid container></Grid>
          </Box>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

I have some trouble understanding React Context, but I followed several tutorials and there is always something wrong..
I had created an authentication in another way, but I had a bug to retrieve userId (at the first connection it was "undefined", defined after a page refresh, but userId wasn't sent to the back),now I changed the auth, but nothing is injected in LS...
Can anyone help me, please?
I've been blocking on it for a long time and I don't have anymore courage to completely change the project..

Comment: log what is in action.payload in your reducer after LOGIN action to see if action's payload is correct. Also, how do you know localStorage is empty? Your code doesn't try to read from it

Comment: I know LS is empty because there's nothing inside (Chrome -> Application ->  Storage). And thanks for the advice. I tried console.log and I get "Error dispatchAuthState is not a function"